# overlaps the location of another project in zend studio?

Tags: php, zend-studio

I do not know, How to add the same project in the workspace with same name.

I have setup a project in zend studio. I have setup a workspace xyz. There I added two projects of php.

projectA and projectB

then because of some issue, I removed project by by deleting from workspace xyz.

Then I try to add a fresh copy of projectB into my workspace xyz but zend studio is giving error and not adding the same project.

```
error was coming: overlaps the location of another project
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to add the projectB from the same location. just copy projectB complete folder to another location and then add it into zend studio workspace. For example:

You have projectB in location: c:\projectB
You should move it to D drive - d:\projectB

then try to add projectB into zend studio workspace, everything will be fixed.